# View details control on ax 2012 form

Tags: forms, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

I would like to bring view details button in my form when right clicked on my form view details should be shown like in standard any form for example when we right click on item number field on the form we have view details option when clicked that opens the details form of that item.

I tried using the normal right click method but could not succeed, please help me how to bring the view details functionality in my custom form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create *Display Menu Item* with the selected form.

Then you can set newly created menu item for the `FormRef` property of the *Table*.

Answer (score 4):

To have the "View details" standard context menu, the following must be true:

1. The foreign key (FK) must have a relation defined on the table of the key
2. The table pointed to by the FK must have a form
3. The form must have a display menu item
4. The menu item must have the same name as the table or the `FormRef` property must be set
5. The menu item must have security set up, and the user must have read access (or better)

Running the Best Practice check will usually spot the errors.

This [blog entry](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/david_kidder/archive/2012/03/05/referencetable-amp-table-references-on-edt.aspx) explains it nicely.