# Which class generate right click menu?

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012, right-click, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

I would like to check about *right menu*

[image]

I need to give info about *View details* menu. Which class or form manage the menu?

-> I need to find *label* (sys or similar) behind *View details* button , and I would like to check about how generate this tight click menu.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean, you need to give info about the "view details" menu? Do you need to find out where the target of the `View Detail` click is? Or do you want to try and modify the right-click context menu to add your own menu items? Can you clarify?

Comment: Thanks @Alex Kwinty for you comment. I edited my post. 

I added this comment:
"I need to find _label_ (sys or similar) behind _View details_ button , and I would like to check about how generate this tight click menu."

Answer (score 2):

Which class or form manage the menu? A kernel method.

The labels for menu is placed here:
**C:\Program Files\Microsoft Dynamics AX\60\Server\AOS-name\bin\AxSysEN-US.ktd**
or wherever your AOS bin directory is placed. Do not mess with the kernel text files.

How to get a "View details", formerly "Go to main table" item is covered in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27148705/4509).
See also this [forum answer](https://community.dynamics.com/ax/f/microsoft-dynamics-ax-forum/220571/go-to-main-table-form---how-to-select-the-default-row/591309).

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Jan B. Kjeldsen.
I would like to find the label behind "View details". In addition I would like to do a some change , do you have some adbice about this? I appreciated your answer.

Comment: The label is in the kernel label file. Change what, advice about what? You have not specified.

Comment: I would just like to see what label is behind "View details". There is no way to see in to Kernel label file? Thanks.